# How is the confidentiality feature of the membership service of Hyperledger is used in a chaincode?

Tags: hyperledger

Given the following Hyperledger set-up:

Company:

```
- 1 membership service
- 1 VP
```

Partner A:

```
- 1 VP
```

Partner B:

```
- 1 VP
```

Assume that there are 3 types of data that can be stored in the blockchain:

```
- dataCommon (can be read by Company, Partner A, Partner B)
- dataA (can be read only by Company and Partner A)
- dataB (can be read only by Company and Partner B)
```

How do I use the confidentiality feature of the membership service so that dataCommon, dataA, and dataB's access rights (as shown above) are enforced?

If dataA is readable only by Company and Partner A, does that mean that during the validation process of dataA, only the VPs of Company and Partner A will participate?  If yes, is this done automatically or do I need to do some manual configuration in the VPs so that they know which data they need to participate in the validation process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know the confidentiality feature is not yet implemented. It is expected in the version 1.0 next year.